# I studied in accordance with Apple's official tutorial, but the following error occurred

Tags: swift

I don't know how to solve this problem
"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key setDefaultLabelText"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WSSq.png)

Comment: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key setDefaultLabelText"

Comment: Are you sure setDefaultLabelText is correctly connected from your storyboard to your swift file?

Comment: pls refer this before asking a query  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please put the actual question in the title - not a general statement of your experience, or people won't bother clicking on it. Do you have any code/further details you could give us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This errors occurs when your connections are not in-sync, or if you connected it improperly. Perhaps you changed the name of the func after connecting your storyboard item to it. Something like that will give you this error.

Simply delete the connection in your storyboard. You should be looking for a connection like the one shown below:

[image]

Then reconnect it as you did before, and everything should work again.

Comment: 3q,I try again,and success

Comment: @APTX2017 glad to hear it worked out. If this answer helped you, then upvoting and/or accepting the answer may help others in the future